# Exclude words when they are followed by certain character

Tags: regex

I have a string with a number of variables (country, age, interests) and I would like to exclude the variables which have no value, but keep the other groupings.

So for this example:

> &country=&age=23&interests=star+wars

I'd want to exclude **&country=**, but keep the rest.

This is my current regex: `([^&].*?=)(.*?)(?=\&|$)`

Group 1 captures: `country=, age=, interests=`

Group 2 captures:`'', 23, star+wars`

Essentially I would like to exclude a word after its equal sign is followed by an ampersand (which indicates it contains no value).

Comment: The slimmest regex for this would be `([^&]+)=([^&]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class `[^&]` with `+` quantifier:

```
([^&=]+)=([^&]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LtdhD3/3).

**Details**:

- `([^&=]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more chars other than `&`
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `([^&]+)` - Group 2 capturing *one or more* symbols other than `&`

[image]

Comment: Super! Thank you! Can I ask for a small edit. How do I exclude the equal sign, so that the regexp purely captures the variable and its value. Again many thanks! (cant accept answer yet due to time limit)

Comment: It is in my note, but I will adjust.